# Grading/correcting/? assignments

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

In the course I'm currently teaching, I give out assignments which the students do and submit for me to later review and comment on. They either pass this task, or they need to revise their work. They are not graded on this work, it's basically just a hurdle they have to jump over.

What would be the proper word for what I do in this? I'm not really grading the assignments, which otherwise would be the natural choice (i.e. if it were an exam). Is "correcting assignments" a valid expression? Or "reviewing"? Or something else?

Comment: If you're giving feedback about standards of performance, it is 'grading', but because the term usually carries the strong exam resonance in your situation, a less marked (!) synonym would be less confusing. 'Appraising' might work (though we're back to wrong connotations with 'appraisal'). 'Giving feedback' gets away from the 'pass/fail' implications. But really, in your case there _is_ a pass/not pass dichotomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making corrections for the students, you are "correcting" their papers.

If you are only pointing out which of their responses need to be corrected, you are "reviewing" and "marking" their papers.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain the most common term at school and university level is (in my experience):

> **marking** assignments

The following is the entry from the [Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mark).

> **mark** *verb* (PIECE OF WORK)
>
> mainly UK
>
> (US usually **grade**)
>
> **to correct mistakes in and give points for a piece of work**:
>
> • *I was up half the night marking exam papers.*

I’ve been there.